# Flutter: How to correctly create a custom Widget from an existing one and use its properties (some times conditionally)

Tags: flutter

I’m trying to create a Widget that is almost the same as an existing Widget. That means that if I want to use the properties of the existing one, I will have to pass them to it from my custom Widget. In this example I will create a Widget that contains a TextField. My approach would be something like:

```
class MyTextFieldWithPadding extends StatelessWidget {

  final Function onTap;
  final ValueSetter<String> onChanged;
  final TextEditingController controller;
  final double padding;

  MyTextFieldWithPadding({this.controller, this.onTap, this.onChanged, this.padding});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(padding),
        child: TextField(
          onTap: onTap,
          onChanged: onChanged,
          controller: controller,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

But I have one issue: not always I want to pass a value to a property of the TextField, for example an onTap function. Currently I haven’t solved how to conditionally pass an argument to a nested widget, so to speak. If I create a Widget like this:

```
             MyTextFieldWithPadding(
                controller: controller,
                onChanged: (value){
                  print(value);
                },
              )
```

I get always exceptions if I didn't use all the properties because, yes, they're null.

> The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building
> MyTextFieldWithPadding: The method '>=' was called on null. Receiver:
> null Tried calling: >=(0.0)

etc.

Maybe there are other approaches for creating a widget and I would be very thankful if you could give me some feedback about this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1: default value in the parameter list

```
class MyTextFieldWithPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final double padding;
  MyTextFieldWithPadding({Key key, this.padding = 10.0}) : super(key: key);
}
```

While being more idiomatic, you will have to define the default everywhere if you nest your custom Widget.

Example:

```
class MyOtherWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final double padding;
  MyOtherWidget({Key key, this.padding = 10.0}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MyTextFieldWithPadding(padding: padding);
  }
}
```

If you don't, padding will be null in `MyTextFieldWithPadding`.

So, if you nest your Custom Widget, it might be better to...

### Solution 2: Initialize to the default value

```
class MyTextFieldWithPadding extends StatelessWidget {
  final double _padding;
  MyTextFieldWithPadding({Key key, padding}) :
    _padding = padding ?? 10.0,
    super(key: key);
}
```

No need to define the default value everywhere. If it's null, the default will be used.

### Side note: callback methods

```
class MyCustomWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String _label;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  
  MyTextFieldWithPadding({Key key, this.onPressed}) :
    _label = label ?? 'CLICK',
    super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Elevated(
      onPressed: () => onPressed?.call(),
      child: Text(_label),
    );
  }
}
```

`onPressed` callback will be called only if it's not `null`.

Comment: Man, that Padding thing was a very obvious mistake. I'll not correct it in order to help others that pass through this kind of things. However, the side note is quite useful. I'll check these notes of yours, thanks.

Comment: I have to say, however, that if I had `cursorWidth` as a final variable in my main widget, and also had it in the nested widget like: `cursorWidth`: `cursorWidth` but didn't assign it a value, that would throw the kind of exceptions a mean, for instance `Failed assertion: line 247 pos 15: 'cursorWidth != null && cursorWidth >= 0.0': is not true.` How would you deal with that. Would you always validate such things or assign them a default value?